# SyntaxError: Unexpected Indentifier while compiling ejs problem

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have encountered the error below when running the app in windows.

```
    SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in \path\views\landing.ejs while compiling ejs
If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at Template.compile (\path\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:626:12)
    at Object.compile (\path\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:366:16)
    at handleCache (\path\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:215:18)
    at tryHandleCache (\path\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:254:16)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (\path\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:459:10)
    at View.render (\path\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (\path\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (\path\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (\path\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1012:7)
```

Here is my code snippet:

```
<% include partials/header %>
    <h1>Landing Page</h1>
    <a href ="/campgrounds">View all campgrounds</a>
    <p>Trademark</p>    
<% include partials/footer %>
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
<%- include('header'); -%>
<h1>
  Title
</h1>
<p>
  My page
</p>
<%- include('footer'); -%>
```

Comment: That was fast! Thanks! Where should I refer some guide in using those `<%-  include('foo') -%>`?

Comment: When I do this I get this error: https://pastebin.com/yterFEKE

Answer (score 12):

```
<%- include('partials/header'); -%>
<h1>
  Title
</h1>
<p>
  My page
</p>
<%- include('partials/footer'); -%>
```

Before using this you must use app.set("view engine","ejs") in your main file.

Answer (score 3):

Or

```
<%- include('partials/header'); %>
<h1>
  Title
</h1>
<p>
  My page
</p>
<%- include('partials/footer'); %>
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

hopefully this will help you. Check out the tags :