# Unexpected token '.' in EJS-Lint

Tags: node.js, express

How do I fix this problem?
I'm new to HTML & Node.js programming. I tried but it was harder than I expected

```
<!-- File name: index.ejs
     Author's name: Hae Yeon Kang (Lucy)
     web site name: Hae Yeon's Portfolio Website
     URL: haeyeonkang.azurewebsites.net
     file description: This is the main page of the website.
-->

<% include ../partials/header %>

<body class="full">
    <header id="top" class="header">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3 panel panel-default">
            <div class="text-vertical-center">
                <img src="images/logo.png" alt="HAE YEON KANG" width="300" />
                <p>
                    <br/>
                </p>
                <h4 style="font-size: 15pt; font-family: Courier New;">
                    Hi, it is great to meet you. 
                    <br/>I'm Hae Yeon Kang, a Computer Programmer, <br/>and welcome to my portfolio website.
                </h4>
                <br/>
                <a href="/about" class="btn btn-dark btn-lg">Click Here!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <% include ../partials/footer %>
```

`

Eror that it exported

```
Unexpected token '.' in D:\hack\hacktoberfest-museum-main\hacktoberfest-museum-main\PortOr\Node.js-Portfolio-Website\server\views\pages\index.ejs while compiling ejs If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint: https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '.' in D:\hack\hacktoberfest-museum-main\hacktoberfest-museum-main\PortOr\Node.js-Portfolio-Website\server\views\pages\index.ejs while compiling ejs

If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at Template.compile (D:\hack\hacktoberfest-museum-main\node_modules\.pnpm\ejs@3.1.8\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:673:12)
    at Object.compile (D:\hack\hacktoberfest-museum-main\node_modules\.pnpm\ejs@3.1.8\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:398:16)
    at handleCache (D:\hack\hacktoberfest-museum-main\node_modules\.pnpm\ejs@3.1.8\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:235:18)
    at tryHandleCache (D:\hack\hacktoberfest-museum-main\node_modules\.pnpm\ejs@3.1.8\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:274:16)
    at exports.renderFile [as engine] (D:\hack\hacktoberfest-museum-main\node_modules\.pnpm\ejs@3.1.8\node_modules\ejs\lib\ejs.js:491:10)
    at View.render (D:\hack\hacktoberfest-museum-main\node_modules\.pnpm\express@4.18.2\node_modules\express\lib\view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (D:\hack\hacktoberfest-museum-main\node_modules\.pnpm\express@4.18.2\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:657:10)
    at Function.render (D:\hack\hacktoberfest-museum-main\node_modules\.pnpm\express@4.18.2\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:609:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (D:\hack\hacktoberfest-museum-main\node_modules\.pnpm\express@4.18.2\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:1039:7)
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5404830/node-js-ejs-including-a-partial) not worked also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59106739/syntaxerror-unexpected-indentifier-while-compiling-ejs-problem).

It just weird that I tried pnpm install to requirement and it doesn't work.

Comment: Original link GIT https://github.com/lucykang/Node.js-Portfolio-Website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your file references are not in quotations, they need to be like this:

`<% include "../partials/header" %>`

Also it looks you're using the wrong syntax to comment. Since this is an `.erb` file, and not an `.html` file you need to use:

`<%# commented line %>`

instead of `<!-- ... -->`.

Comment: It worked! Thanks a lot! 
also, I found that just easier way that just unorganised thing by just "include header"